# How do I access services of UPnP device?

Tags: c++, windows, com, upnp

The device: Belkin Wemo Switch
Dev environment: MS VC++ 2010 on Windows7

I'm trying to enumerate the services of a UPnP device using C++ from Windows.

I've got the `IUPnPDevice` pointer and can access several properties.
I've got the `IUPnPServices` pointer and can count the correct number of services (7).
I use `QueryInterface()` to get the `IEnumVARIANT` pointer (which appears to succeed).
However, the `Next()` method always fails with `HRESULT` of `0x80040500` - which translates as `Windows error 1280 (0x500) - ERROR_ALREADY_FIBER`.
This error does not make any sense to me.

(I've tried using both `IEnumVARIANT` and `IEnumUnknown` - as the docs indicate it could be either, but both produce the same result.)

I've included below the complete source file, plus the output it produces.
[Note: It's hardcoded to use the udn of my own device]

I'd be very grateful if anyone can help as I'm currently stuck.

Best regards,
Dave

Code:

```
// UpnpTest1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <upnp.h>

static void DumpComError(const TCHAR *api, HRESULT hr);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int retcode=-1; // assume failure

  HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
  if (hr==S_OK)
  {
    IUPnPDeviceFinder *deviceFinder=0;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UPnPDeviceFinder, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUPnPDeviceFinder, (void**)&deviceFinder);
    if (hr==S_OK)
    {
      IUPnPDevice *device=0;
      hr = deviceFinder->FindByUDN(L"uuid:Socket-1_0-221239K11002F6", &device);
      if (hr==S_OK)
      {
        if (device)
        {
          TCHAR *manufacturer=0, *manufacturerUrl=0;
          TCHAR *description=0, *name=0, *modelUrl=0;
          TCHAR *serialNumber=0, *udn=0, *upc=0, *deviceType=0;
          TCHAR *presentationUrl=0;

          device->get_ManufacturerName(&manufacturer);
          device->get_ManufacturerURL(&manufacturerUrl);
          device->get_Description(&description);
          device->get_FriendlyName(&name);
          device->get_ModelURL(&modelUrl);
          device->get_SerialNumber(&serialNumber);
          device->get_UniqueDeviceName(&udn);
          device->get_UPC(&upc);
          device->get_Type(&deviceType);
          device->get_PresentationURL(&presentationUrl);

          _tprintf(_T("MANUFACTURER: %s [%s]\n"), manufacturer, manufacturerUrl);
          _tprintf(_T("MODEL:        %s [%s]\n              [%s]\n"), description, name, modelUrl);
          _tprintf(_T("DEVICE:       serial=%s\n              udn=%s\n              upc=%s\n              type=%s\n"), serialNumber, udn, upc, deviceType);
          _tprintf(_T("URL:          %s\n"), presentationUrl);

          IUPnPServices *services=0;
          hr = device->get_Services(&services);
          if (hr==S_OK)
          {
            if (services)
            {
              long numberOfServices=0;
              services->get_Count(&numberOfServices);

              if (numberOfServices>0)
              {
                IUnknown *unknown=0;
                hr = services->get__NewEnum(&unknown);
                if (hr==S_OK)
                {
                  if (unknown)
                  {
                    IEnumVARIANT *enumInterface=0;
                    hr = unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IEnumVARIANT,(void**)&enumInterface);
                    if (enumInterface)
                    {
                      VARIANT var;
                      unsigned long fetched=0;
                      hr = enumInterface->Next(1, &var, &fetched);

                      if (hr==S_OK)
                      {

                      }
                      else
                        DumpComError(_T("IEnumVARIANT::Next"), hr);
                    }
                    else
                      DumpComError(_T("IUnknown::QueryInterface"), hr);
                  }
                  else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get enumeration interface.\n");
                }
                else
                  DumpComError(_T("IUPnPServices::get__NewEnum"), hr);
              }
              else
                fprintf(stderr, "No services available.\n");
            }
            else
              fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get services collection.\n");
          }
          else
            DumpComError(_T("IUPnPDevice::get_Services"), hr);
        }
        else
          fprintf(stderr, "Device not found.\n");
      }
      else
        DumpComError(_T("IUPnPDeviceFinder::FindByUDN"), hr);
    }
    else
      DumpComError(_T("CoCreateIndex"), hr);
  }
  else
    DumpComError(_T("CoInitialize"), hr);

  return retcode;
}

static void AddBoolToString(const TCHAR *name, bool value, TCHAR *buf, int &i, int max)
{
  if (name && *name && value && buf && i>=0)
    i += _snwprintf_s(&buf[i], max-i, (max-i-1)*sizeof(TCHAR), _T("%s%s=YES"), (i>0? _T("; "): _T("")), name);
}

static void AddIntToString(const TCHAR *name, int value, TCHAR *buf, int &i, int max)
{
  if (name && *name && value && buf && i>=0)
    i += _snwprintf_s(&buf[i], max-i, (max-i-1)*sizeof(TCHAR), _T("%s%s=%d"), (i>0? _T("; "): _T("")), name, value);
}

static void DumpComError(const TCHAR *api, HRESULT hr)
{
  bool failure   = (hr&0x80000000? true: false);
  bool severe    = (hr&0x40000000? true: false);
  bool microsoft = (hr&0x20000000? false: true);
  bool ntStatus  = (hr&0x10000000? true: false);
  bool xBit      = (hr&0x08000000? true: false);
  int facility   = (hr&0x07FF0000)>>16;
  int code       = (hr&0x0000FFFF);

  TCHAR buf[1024]={0};
  int bufsize = sizeof(buf)/sizeof(TCHAR);
  int i=0;

  AddBoolToString(_T("failure"), failure, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddBoolToString(_T("severe"), severe, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddBoolToString(_T("microsoft"), microsoft, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddBoolToString(_T("ntStatus"), ntStatus, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddBoolToString(_T("xBit"), xBit, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddIntToString(_T("facility"), facility, buf, i, bufsize);
  AddIntToString(_T("code"), code, buf, i, bufsize);

  _ftprintf(stderr, _T("\n%s() failed, hr=0x%08x\n[%s]\n"), api, hr, buf);
}
```

Output:
It produces following output:

```
MANUFACTURER: Belkin International Inc. [http://www.belkin.com/]
MODEL:        Belkin Plugin Socket 1.0 [WeMo Switch]
              [http://www.belkin.com/plugin/]
DEVICE:       serial=221239K11002F6
              udn=uuid:Socket-1_0-221239K11002F6
              upc=123456789
              type=urn:Belkin:device:controllee:1
URL:          http://192.168.1.16:49153/pluginpres.html

IEnumVARIANT::Next() failed, hr=0x80040500
[failure=YES; microsoft=YES; facility=4; code=1280]
```

**EDIT:**

After a lot of dead-ends, I have managed to get this working by manually building the SOAP requests, and sending the requests via TCP using Windows sockets. Tricky bit was getting the syntax just right as I had no experience of SOAP before. [UPnP was useful to identify the IP address & port number - as these can change]. Once up and running - it's actually a lot simpler than the UPnP interface. Let me know if you're interested and I can post the code... It doesn't directly answer the question I posed here, so it wouldn't make sense to answer my question with this detail.

However, if you're interested, let me know and I can post the code.

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Note: From this page [http://www.issackelly.com/blog/2012/07/30/wemo-hacking/] you can see the list of services, so in theory I should be able to access the service directly using IUPnPServices::get_Item() however, I can't figure out what the correct format for serviceId (first parameter)...

Comment: Note2: I tried using IUPnPService::get_Item( L"urn:Belkin:serviceId:basicevent1", &serviceId); however the HRESULT returned is the same as before (0x80040500)

Comment: Yes @user390935 , post your code. I was looking for platform neutral SSDP client.

Answer (score 2):

HRESULT of 0x80040500 is not what you think, but [UPNP_E_INVALID_DOCUMENT](http://vdfwinapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Include/UPnP.Idl). For explanation  of how such ambiguity is possible, see [my answer in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536989/886653).

My guess is that your Belkin device is giving non-conformant device description or service description XML. Non-conformant doesn't necessarily mean broken format, UPnP specification has tons of secondary requirements. Try Device Spy from Intel Developer Tools (link at bottom of the other answer), if the device pops up, then run Device Validator from the same suite on it.

Comment: Thanks for this... I should have known as the Facility was 4. I guess this means that Windows doesn't like the response back from the device.

Comment: Yes, that's my guess. HRESULT is a horrible legacy of 20 years old compatibility with OS/2. There is only one FACILITY_ITF for all "user defined codes" which is bad enough in itself, but Microsoft is using the same facility for its own new APIs, where it could have used another unused code.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is similar, in that UPnPDeviceFinder simply doesn't work. It never sends out the UPnP Search packet, so the devices don't respond. The only way to get it to work is if you also use windows media player or the "Cast To Device" menu (which is WMP) to initiate the search. As it is UPnPDeviceFinder will return some devices, only if they happen to be broadcasting at that moment, but even finding an XBox (another Microsoft product) doesn't work in the examples without other activity going on.